# Show all DOM nodes in html div

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I want to show all the nodes of my html page inside a div.

What i have so far (js):

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
div3.innerHTML = nodes;
```

And html:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="1-1">
      <div id="div1"></div><br>
      <div id="div2"></div><br>
      <div id="div3"></div><br>
      <div id="div4"></div><br>
      <div id="div5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script201.js" rel="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

The output I get from this code in div3: `[object HTMLCollection]`
How do I get all the nodes to show like:

```
BODY
DIV
DIV
DIV
DIV
DIV
DIV
DIV
SCRIPT
```

So every node in the file basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through all the nodes so that you get the *nodeName* property individually.

***Please Note:*** Since *document* object has some other tags like `HTML`, `HEAD`, `STLYLE`, `SCRIPT` etc., all of them will be targeted with `*` selector.

```js
var nodes = [...document.getElementsByTagName("*")];
nodes.forEach(function(el){
  div3.innerHTML += el.nodeName + ' ';
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="1-1">
        <div id="div1"></div><br>
        <div id="div2"></div><br>
        <div id="div3"></div><br>
        <div id="div4"></div><br>
        <div id="div5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script201.js" rel="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `element_name.querySelectorAll('*')` to get all elements inside it.

```js
var b=document.getElementById('div3')
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(e=>b.innerHTML+=e.nodeName + "<br>")
```

```html
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="1-1">
    <div id="div1"></div><br>
    <div id="div2"></div><br>
    <div id="div3"></div><br>
    <div id="div4"></div><br>
    <div id="div5"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="script201.js" rel="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `querySelectorAll` method, which is used to select all the nodes based on the parameter we passed. for example if we pass * inside `document.querySelectorAll('*')`, it selects all the node in the document. "*" is the universal selector.

```js
var allNode=document.querySelectorAll('*')
console.log(allNode)
```

```html
<body>
<div id="content">
<div>
    <div id="div1"></div><br>
    <div id="div2"></div><br>
    <div id="div3"></div><br>
    <div id="div4"></div><br>
    <div id="div5"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="script201.js" rel="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```